# Extract value from a string using bash

Tags: bash, macos, parsing

First time I need to use bash :(

How do I extract the code of RequestUUID which is contained in variable RESPONSE on two lines?

```
RESPONSE="No errors uploading '/Users/myApp.zip'.
RequestUUID = dwe344r-aa9a-498f-8a82-b13a892a0046"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a string substitution

```
echo ${RESPONSE/*=/}
```

Comment: I propose this small improvement: `echo "${RESPONSE/*= /}"`

Comment: Yes. But without double quotes the result is the same.